# Dockerized react app differences between running the image with and without docker-compose

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

```
// Dockerfile 

# pull base image
FROM node:10.15.1-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY ./package.json ./
COPY ./yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn global add react-scripts@3.4.1 // not sure if this is even necessary


# add app
COPY . ./

# start app
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

Command I'm running to build it:

```
docker build -t matrix-fe:dev .
```

Command to run it:

```
docker run -it --rm -v ${PWD}:/app -v /app/node_modules -p 3000:3000 -e CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true matrix-fe:dev
```

And then this is my composer yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  matrix-fe:
    container_name: matrix-fe
    build:
      context: ./a-fe
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - './a-fe:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

Then to build and run it:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

Error I'm getting:

```
matrix-fe    | yarn run v1.13.0
matrix-fe    | $ react-scripts start
matrix-fe    | It looks like you're trying to use TypeScript but do not have typescript installed.
matrix-fe    | Please install typescript by running yarn add typescript.
matrix-fe    | If you are not trying to use TypeScript, please remove the tsconfig.json file from your package root (and any TypeScript files).
matrix-fe    |
```

Why is this happening? I can obviously try to also install `typescript`, but it is a dependency in `package.json` and should be installed, I also added `node_modules` to path. How is running the image with and without `docker-compose` different? Compose does create a different image called `matrix_matrix-fe`, but then `Dockerfile` hasn't changed. `docker-compose.yml` is in a top level folder, structure looks like this:

```
/matrix
  /a-fe
    ./package.json
    ./Dockerfile
    ...
  /a-be
./docker-compose.yml
```

Help me understand what's different, volumes are same, ENV variables are same, not seeing anything off.

Edit: forgot to mention that running the image without `docker-compose` doesn't output errors, it's working properly.

Comment: If you delete all of the `volumes:` and `docker run -v` options, does it run consistently?  You're overwriting basically everything the Dockerfile builds with mounts, and since you're telling Docker that the `node_modules` directory contains user data that must not be updated, you can get inconsistent behavior.  Given what you've shown running this process without Docker using a host `node` installation might be easier.

Comment: @DavidMaze
Removing `volumes` in `docker-compose` runs app without errors, but hot reload isn't working and any code changes I make aren't reflected if I refresh manually. The first volume I'm mounting so hot-reload works, the second one I'm mounting to overwrite `node_modules`. Removing and adding `volumes` in `docker-compose.yml` did help the app to run properly, why did that work? Volumes are needed for local development, running with Docker is needed so I can run BE and FE services at the same time (BE service not in `yml`).

Comment: Actually, second mount (`/app/node_modules`) probably achieves the opposite -- prevents overwriting `node_modules` by the first mount (`./a-fe:/app`).